# Unexpected end of input error in command prompt (react-native / firebase)

Tags: react-native

I have an error in my command line when i was going to install firebase to my react-native project.

npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:588446
npm ERR! PBeDiD\nyNyMNVfA7KM95kVz6NxCfMFx/YJLc5HXAn3rgdp9pU+sBgGHcAHvgm2TLjYK\
npm ERR!                                                                      ^

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bishop\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-06T05_00_06_781Z-debug.log

Comment: How did you install that?

Answer (score 1):

**-->**Try removing cached .npm directory stored from the previous versions of npm. It is placed at ~/.npm
i.e.

```
rm -rf ~/.npm
```

**-->**1. npm install firebase
Only the one-step process.
2.Node version tried- 8.9.3 and 6.3 versions
3.Npm version tried - 5.4 and 3.2
4.Also tried deleting node_packages and then npm install.
5.Also tried including firebase in package.json and then npm install.
6.Also tried the same process with yarn and bower.